# Convert uneven sampling rate to uniform sampling rate in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have some velocity data where the sampling rate is uneven (pictured below. Vertical lines on the signal are the sampling points). More samples are recorded when the velocity is higher, and fewer samples are recorded when the velocity is low (i.e. not much is happening). I need to convert this into a uniform sampling rate using MATLAB.

I want to convert this into an even sampling rate. My first thought was I could simply do a spline fit and then discretise that fit. But I am losing a lot of information that is crucial and to not lose the information, I tried increasing the sampling rate but the computational cost of that is very high. I mostly need an even rate so that I can apply different filters on it properly. I need to remove the high-frequency bumps on the decreasing side of the signal which are not reduced any further by a lowpass filter hence I want to try a moving average filter.

The picture below has already been lowpass filtered <0.001Hz.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. (I tried asking in signal processing but for some reason I cannot join the community)

Comment: I would [interp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/interp.html) the data then run it through different filters to see where they lead.

Comment: @XZhang how would interp help? The uneven sampling would still be there no matter how much I increase the sampling rate right

Comment: Oh it should be [interp1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html). My mistake. It is comparable to spline, but with additional choices for balancing performance and accuracy.

Comment: I see. Thanks! That might just be what I need